# Find Chrome packaged app ssid

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, ssid

I'm searching for a way to find the currently connected essid (and/or mac address) in a packaged chrome app.

Is it possible to find it using device permissions? I know it's not possible via javascript due to the sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no.

Longer answer is: you can get the list of devices and their IP addresses out [getNetworkList](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html#method-getNetworkList) on the socket API.

```
chrome.socket.getNetworkList(function(interfaces) {
    for(var i in interfaces) {
      var interface = interfaces[i];
      var opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.value = interface.address;
      opt.innerText = interface.name + " - " + interface.address;
      hosts.appendChild(opt);
    }
  });
```